# Op amp has a biased output

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, theory

I'm designing an op amp circuit to amplify 20mV, 18kHz square wave up to measurable levels (~2-3V). Why is the output signal:

- Biased at ~400mV
- Triangular (high output capacitance? is that a thing?) ?

Op amp is chosen to have maximum slew rate (1V/uS).

[image: Schematic here]

As suggested, I've tried a couple of higher-GBWP op amps and none of them work for some reason. Why is that?

[image: Another schematic here]

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: "Why is the output: -biased, -triangular?"

Comment: Andrey-do you realize that the noisy signal as shown is NOT used as an input for the opamp (R8_C1 provide lowpass filtering).

Comment: @LvW Yeah, that's kinda useless at the moment.

Comment: The reason for offset is simple: you have a low-pass filter on the input to your amplifier. You probably want to block DC with a high-pass filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 (biasing): It is no surprise that the output signal contains a dc part because the input signal is centered upon a dc voltage. However, the dc ouput level cannot be verified simply by amplifying the input dc voltage because the form of the output signal has changed.

Question 2 (form): There are two different effects which influence the output form: (a) Limited and frequency-dependent small signal gain of the opamp and (b) limited slew rate of the opamp. The slew rate may be the reason for the observed behaviour in case of a wideband opamp model.

**EDIT 1:** Simulations based on the LF411 model show pretty good results (as expected): Output 2.3Vpp (between 0.7 and 2v) with slight distortions and a very small noise component (5 Mhz) riding on the top of the signal.

**EDIT 2:** I think, both questions are answered: DC portion and signal form distortion.

Comment: But all wideband op amps i've used have order of magnitude higher GWBP than the original one.

Comment: What about slew rate? Try to confiorm my results with LF411.

Comment: @LvW: You may have a typo, the Vpp should 1.3V or so. With MCP601, the Vpp is 2V, with DC level 1V.

Comment: Sorry-you are right: 1.3Vpp.

Comment: But andrey g's result is not reasonable. There must be something wrong.

Comment: Which "result" are you referring to?

Comment: Um, i mean andrey g's result is **not reasonable**. So i suggest him to choose another simulator and try.

Comment: I've simulated the LF411 and MCP601 version in PSpice. In andre's results, the AC portion of the signal is too low.

Comment: In my simulation (LF411) the AC riding on the pulse is 0.2 mVpp (millivolts pp) . Too low? Remember: Input filtering and amplification at 5MHz!!

Answer (score 6):

I would say the output was offset at 1 volt and this is approximately 100 times higher than the offset on the input waveform. Given your amp is configured to have a gain of about 100, there is no surprise here.

The triangulated output is due to the poor gain-bandwidth-product of the op-amp you chose. You want a gain of 100 and you are feeding it 18kHz and it has a GBWP of 1 million Hz.

If the gain is 100, then the "usable" bandwidth of the circuit is 10 kHz but you are exceeding that with your 18 kHz signal hence the circuit acts like a low pass filter at about 10 kHz.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that the input signal is offset. Is it really? Also i've updated original question with different op amp simulations.

Comment: @andreyg - ask yourself - what is the average DC level of the input signal as shown on the pictures you provide.

Comment: @andreyg: I think you may have some error in your simulations. It seems your simulator is "proteus", right? From your simulation graphs, it seems there are some "ripple" on your op amp's out. Can you split the MIC and OUT into two different graph? It seems your scales not right.

Comment: @diverger Tried that, there are actually no ripples, it's a perfectly level signal. Yes, i'm using proteus.

Comment: Please check your LF411's result, i can see small ripples on OUT in your picture. That is, OUT isn't perfect DC.

Comment: @diverger You were right, there are ripples following input's form going from 1.476 to 1.499V.

Comment: I think you can try other simulators, such as CircuitLab, i'm not familiar with proteus. I can simulate your circuit with PSpice, the result is a 500mV peak-peak AC signal riding on a 1V or so DC level.

Comment: What kind of "ripples" are you both speaking of? I think, the input signal has a noise component of 5 MHz?

Comment: @andreyg regards the other op-amps you have used, you need to choose op-amps that have higher GBWP an are capable of working with inputs at 0V OR use a negative rail as well as a positive rail for the op-amps supply.

Comment: @diverger I'll try different simulators.

Comment: @LvW By ripples we mean the signal itself, not the noise part.

Comment: @Andy What is the characteristic that indicates than an op amp is capable of working with 0V inputs?

Comment: @andreyg it's called a "rail-to-rail input capability". I believe the MCP601 does have this capability btw.

Comment: Andy- why do you think that rail-to-rail is an issue here? I don`t think so.

Comment: @LvW the op-amp's negative rail is 0V and the input signal appears to be very close to 0V

Comment: For the LF411 the output does not go below 0.7 volts (my simulation) - however, this may be caused (also) by the opamp`s offset voltage. Nevertheless, I don`t think that the observed signal form (main point of the OP`s question) has something to do with rail-to-rail capabilities.

Comment: @lvw the input rail to rail capabilities is crucial for this design to work. With an input that ranges between 0mV and 20mV, the device has to have rail-to-rail input capability. The LF411 does not have this capability and is not a suitable choice unless andreyg biases the inputs to take them into the usable range for an LF411.

Comment: Andy-no doubt about this (no "suitable choice"). My comment was related to the "triangular" form only!. For my opinion, this was the key point of the OP`s question.